# Insert list to a 2D list at a specific index

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I didn't find a lot about inserting a list to a 2D list.

I tried to use append (which doesn't work because append can't append at specific index) and insert, but insert can't append multiple lists in a list.

I'd like to convert this 2D list

```
[[0, dataABC, date], [0, dataABC, date], [1, dataABC, date], [1, dataABC, date] , [1, dataABC, date]]
```

to a 3D list to get direct access to the list of a specific index.

```
data = [
[[0, dataABC, date],[0, dataABC, date]],
[[1, dataABC, date], [1, dataABC, date], [1, dataABC, date]]
]

print(data[1]):
[1, dataABC, date], [1, dataABC, date], [1, dataABC, date]
```

Comment: you have `data` as variable and also as element of list. is that intentional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are ordered you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> l = [[0, 'data', 'date'], [0, 'data', 'date'], [1, 'data', 'date'], [1, 'data', 'date'] , [1, 'data', 'date']]
>>> results = list(list(v) for k, v in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0]))
>>> results
[[[0, 'data', 'date'], [0, 'data', 'date']], [[1, 'data', 'date'], [1, 'data', 'date'], [1, 'data', 'date']]]
```

If they are not ordered use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for e in l:
...     d[e[0]].append(e)
...
>>> results = list(d.values())
>>> results
[[[0, 'data', 'date'], [0, 'data', 'date']], [[1, 'data', 'date'], [1, 'data', 'date'], [1, 'data', 'date']]]
```